# ng-show to hide a div on form submit

Tags: html, angularjs

I have following markup in my view

```
  <div ng-show="showTheForm" class='col-md-8'>
    <form ng-submit='login()'action="http://localhost/test/signin.php" target='signin' method="post">

     <input type="submit" class='alt-btn' id="signin-button" value="Sign in">
    </form>
 </div>


<div ng-show="!showTheForm" class='col-md-8'>
        <iframe height='600px' width='470px' id="signin" name="signin" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
   </div>
```

When I submit the form I run this function within my `controller`

```
$scope.login = function() {
  //Show the iframe
$scope.showTheForm = false;
}
```

What I want to happen is the form hides and the div with the iframe becomes visible.

The form hides when I submit but the iframe does not become visible and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong?

I read about `$apply` and how it is used to inform angular if a variable is updated. I tried this but it made no effect.

Would anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I assume your login function actually gets called? have you tried using `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`? I think `ng-if` is usually the preferred option anyway for improved performance

Comment: It will, for now I am focusing on showing and hiding the necessary divs. I'll give that a go now. Thanks

Comment: Instate of submitting the form try ajax call. because your form will submitted  i.e  again your page wll reload and then scope will again initialize so you should have to use ajax call angular ajax call

Comment: It just looks odd the way you have assigned your function to the login method... `$scope.login() = function () { }` i've never seen it like that I'm used to seeing it written as `$scope.login = function () { }` without the brackets next to the `$scope` method

Comment: Hi Will you are right, I've since updated that but it has not rectified the problem!!

Comment: Does `http://localhost/test/signin.php` actually return something?

Comment: Can you write something inside second div? Maybe it is about iframe. @zeroflagL

Comment: your iframe should have some element. i have created a plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/n8afHFaVAoRlOvu2qmZv?p=preview

Answer (score -3):

the definition of function in your controller is wrong.

Change function definition from **`$scope.login() = function()`** ==> `$scope.login = function()`

Comment: This should be go into you comment box it not a Answers